# Calculate probability of a flush in poker

Tags: python, simulation, montecarlo, poker

I have the code to keep going through a loop until a flush is made.
now I am trying to make it where I use count to show how many hands are dealt then divide by one to get the probability.

For the code i have right now using count it returns it as 0

```
from collections import namedtuple
from random import shuffle

Card = namedtuple("Card", "suit, rank")

class Deck:
    suits = '♦♥♠♣'
    ranks = '23456789JQKA'

    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = [Card(suit, rank) for suit in self.suits for rank in self.ranks]
        shuffle(self.cards)

    def deal(self, amount):
        return tuple(self.cards.pop() for _ in range(amount))

flush = False
count = 0
while not flush:

    deck = Deck()
    stop = False
    while len(deck.cards) > 5:
        hand = deck.deal(5)
        # (Card(suit='♣', rank='7'), Card(suit='♠', rank='2'), Card(suit='♥', rank='4'), Card(suit='♥', rank='K'), Card(suit='♣', rank='3'))

        if len(set(card.suit for card in hand)) > 1:
            #print(f"No Flush: {hand}")
            continue
        print(f"Yay, it's a Flush: {hand}")
        flush = True
        break
        if flush:
            break
        else:
            count +=1
print(f'Count is {count}')
```

There is a little more code at the top used for init methods if you need that too let me know

Comment: Your loop stops at the first `break` every time you run the code, so the count will never increase.

Comment: Also, stopping the first time you get a flush will never give you a relevant probability. Try an approach more similar to the monte carlo method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method

Comment: @MasonCaiby I got rid of the break but it stays at 0 im not sure where to put the ```if flush:``` then break part so that it'll loop correctly

Comment: You might be interested in this datacamp write up on [estimating general hand probabilities](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/statistics-python-tutorial-probability-1).

Comment: Since you're using code from answers to your other questions, please be so kind to mark them as accepted answers...

Comment: @l.m I was wondering if you have seen my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58106397/3491991)? Is it helpful?

Comment: @zelusp Currently looking through it, I was also fascinated by the monte Carlo simulation It makes waaay more sense now looking at it with graphs and the changes with masons code to yours going more in-depth to get a more accurate result for a flush. then using it to check using 80000 hands as an example makes a lot of sense now for understanding the algorithm then applying it in code. Thank you for giving a more in-depth understanding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code (and what is available in @Mason's answer) will estimate the probability of *eventually* getting your **first** flush. To estimate the probability of getting a flush in *general*, which I believe is what you're after, you have to run that experiment many thousands of times over. In practice this is called a Monte Carlo simulation.

> **Side note**: When I began learning about Monte Carlos I thought they were a sort of "magical", mysteriously complex thing... mostly because their name sounds so exotic. Don't be fooled. "Monte Carlo" is just an overly fancy and [arbitrary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method#History) name for "simulation". They can be quite elementary.

Even so, simulations are kind of magical because you can use them to brute force a solution out of a complex system even when a mathematical model of that system is hard to come by. Say, for example, you don't have a firm understanding of combination or permutation math - which would produce the exact answer to your question *"What are the odds of getting a flush?"*. We can run many simulations of your card game to figure out what that probability would be to a high degree of certainty. I've done that below (commented out parts of your original code that weren't needed):

```
from collections import namedtuple
from random import shuffle
import pandas as pd

#%% What is the likelyhood of getting flush? Mathematical derivation
""" A flush consists of five cards which are all of the same suit.
We must remember that there are four suits each with a total of 13 cards.
Thus a flush is a combination of five cards from a total of 13 of the same suit.
This is done in C(13, 5) = 1287 ways.
Since there are four different suits, there are a total of 4 x 1287 = 5148 flushes possible. 
Some of these flushes have already been counted as higher ranked hands.
We must subtract the number of straight flushes and royal flushes from 5148 in order to
obtain flushes that are not of a higher rank.
There are 36 straight flushes and 4 royal flushes.
We must make sure not to double count these hands.
This means that there are 5148 – 40 = 5108 flushes that are not of a higher rank. 
We can now calculate the probability of a flush as 5108/2,598,960 = 0.1965%.
This probability is approximately 1/509. So in the long run, one out of every 509 hands is a flush."""
"SOURCE: https://www.thoughtco.com/probability-of-a-flush-3126591"

mathematically_derived_flush_probability = 5108/2598960 * 100

#%% What is the likelyhood of getting flush? Monte Carlo derivation

Card = namedtuple("Card", "suit, rank")

class Deck:
    suits = '♦♥♠♣'
    ranks = '23456789JQKA'

    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = [Card(suit, rank) for suit in self.suits for rank in self.ranks]
        shuffle(self.cards)

    def deal(self, amount):
        return tuple(self.cards.pop() for _ in range(amount))

#flush = False
hand_count = 0
flush_count = 0
flush_cutoff = 150 # Increase this number to run the simulation over more hands.
column_names = ['hand_count', 'flush_count', 'flush_probability', 'estimation_error']
hand_results = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)

while flush_count < flush_cutoff:
    deck = Deck()
    while len(deck.cards) > 5:
        hand_count +=1
        hand = deck.deal(5)
        # (Card(suit='♣', rank='7'), Card(suit='♠', rank='2'), Card(suit='♥', rank='4'), Card(suit='♥', rank='K'), Card(suit='♣', rank='3'))
        if len(set(card.suit for card in hand)) == 1:
#            print(f"Yay, it's a Flush: {hand}")
            flush_count +=1
#            break
#        else:
#            print(f"No Flush: {hand}")
        monte_carlo_derived_flush_probability = flush_count / hand_count * 100
        estimation_error = (monte_carlo_derived_flush_probability - mathematically_derived_flush_probability) / mathematically_derived_flush_probability * 100
        hand_df = pd.DataFrame([[hand_count,flush_count,monte_carlo_derived_flush_probability, estimation_error]], columns=column_names)
        hand_results = hand_results.append(hand_df)

#%% Analyze results
# Show how each consecutive hand helps us estimate the flush probability
hand_results.plot.line('hand_count','flush_probability').axhline(y=mathematically_derived_flush_probability,color='r')

# As the number of hands (experiments) increases, our estimation of the actual probability gets better.
# Below the error gets closer to 0 percent as the number of hands increases.
hand_results.plot.line('hand_count','estimation_error').axhline(y=0,color='black')

#%% Memory usage
print("Memory used to store all %s runs: %s megabytes" % (len(hand_results),round(hand_results.memory_usage(index=True,deep=True).sum()/1000000, 1)))
```

In this particular case, thanks to math, we could have just confidently derived the probability of getting a flush as `0.1965%`. To prove that our simulation arrived at the correct answer we can compare its output after 80,000 hands:

[image]

As you can see, our simulated `flush_probability` (in blue) approaches the mathematically derived probability (in black).

Similarly, below is a plot of the `estimation_error` between the simulated probability and the mathematically derived value. As you can see, the estimation error was more than `100%` off in the early runs of the simulation but gradually rose to within `5%` of the error.

[image]

If you were to run the simulation for, say, twice the number of hands, then we would see that the blue and red lines eventually overlap with the black horizontal line in both charts - signifying that the simulated answer becomes equivalent to the mathematically derived answer.

## To simulate or not to simulate?

Finally, you might wonder,

> *"If I can generate a precise answer to a problem by simulating it, then why bother with all the complicated math in the first place?"*

The answer is, as with just about any decision in life, "trade offs".

In our example, we could run the simulation over enough hands to get a precise answer with a high degree of confidence. However, if one is running a simulation because they *don't know* the answer (which is often the case), then one needs to answer another question,

> *"How long do I run the simulation to be confident I have the right answer?"*

The answer to that seems simple:

> *"Run it for a long time."*

Eventually your estimated outputs could converge to a single value such that outputs from additional simulations don't drastically change from prior runs. The problem here is that in some cases, depending on the complexity of the system you're simulating, seemingly convergent output may be a temporary phenomena. That is, if you ran a hundred thousand more simulations, you might begin to see your outputs diverge from what you thought was your stable answer. In a different scenario, despite having run tens of millions of simulations, it could happen that an output still hasn't converged. Do you have the time to program and run the simulation? Or would a mathematical approximation get you there sooner?

There is yet another concern:

> *"What is the cost?"

Consumer computers are relatively cheap today but 30 years ago they cost [$4,000 to $9,000](https://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2019/06/why-30-year-old-macintosh-works-better-todays/591154/) in 2019 dollars. In comparison, a [TI89 only cost $215](https://www.thocp.net/hardware/ti_calculators.htm) (again, in 2019 dollars). So if you were asking this question back in 1990 and you were good with probability math, you could have saved $3,800 by using a TI89. Cost is just as important today: simulating [self-driving](https://techcrunch.com/2019/07/10/waymo-has-now-driven-10-billion-autonomous-miles-in-simulation/) cars and [protein folding](http://blogs.nature.com/news/2012/08/d-wave-quantum-computer-solves-protein-folding-problem.html) can burn many millions of dollars.

Finally, mission critical applications may require both a simulation and a mathematical model to cross check the results of both approaches. A tidy example of this is when Matt Parker of StandUpMaths calculated [the odds of landing on any property in the game of Monopoly](https://youtu.be/ubQXz5RBBtU?t=335) by simulation and confirmed those results with Hannah Fry's mathematical model of the same game.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work for you. It depends on how your `Deck()` is defined though, I guess. I tried to leave your code in a similar state to how you had written it, but had to make some changes so you wouldn't get errors. I also didn't actually run it, since I don't have `Deck` defined.

```
flush = False
count = 0
while not flush:

    deck = Deck()
    stop = False
    while len(deck.cards) > 5:
        hand = deck.deal(5)
        # (Card(suit='♣', rank='7'), Card(suit='♠', rank='2'), Card(suit='♥', rank='4'), Card(suit='♥', rank='K'), Card(suit='♣', rank='3'))

        if len(set(card.suit for card in hand)) > 1:
            print(f"No Flush: {hand}")
        else:
            print(f"Yay, it's a Flush: {hand}")
            flush = True
            break
        count +=1
print(f'Count is {count}')
```

But it will not give you the probability of getting a flush, and you'll honestly probably run out of cards in `deck` before you get a flush in almost every run...

I would consider changing the code to this so, to take out some redundancies.

```
flush = False
count = 0
while not flush:

    deck = Deck()
    while len(deck.cards) > 5:
        hand = deck.deal(5)
        # (Card(suit='♣', rank='7'), Card(suit='♠', rank='2'), Card(suit='♥', rank='4'), Card(suit='♥', rank='K'), Card(suit='♣', rank='3'))

        if len(set(card.suit for card in hand)) == 1:
            print(f"Yay, it's a Flush: {hand}")
            flush = True
            break
        else:
            print(f"No Flush: {hand}")
            count +=1
print(f'Count is {count}')
```

Comment: What would be better to do instead of doing the length of the cards to give me a probability

Comment: That helps alot i see what you did there and it makes alot of more sense now

Comment: You'll also need `Card` defined if you want us to be able to run it.